# How to seach node_modules in Visual Studio Code without changing settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know about `Search: Exclude`, but this approach requires changing settings each time I wish to search `node_modules`. There must be a more efficient way?

Comment: I don't know if it helps and you probably know that option but worth to mention that you can change it per workspace.

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. I do know about this option, but it still requires switching settings back and forth as I wish to exclude node_modules by default.

Comment: You can also set `files to include` to `node_modules` and uncheck `Use exclude settings and ignore files` next to `files to exclude`. It probably not easier though :)

Comment: Do you want to search for files or code within node_modules?  If only files, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jasonnutter.search-node-modules.